# Percentage greater than 2 standard deviations from the mean

Tags: statistics

A question reads: "The weights of $910$ young deer tagged and weighed in a research study are normally distributed with a mean of $86$ pounds and a standard deviation of $2.5$ pounds."

Approximately how many deer weigh more than $91$ pounds?

Since $34.1$% fall within the first standard deviation and $13.6$% fall within the second standard deviation, then $2.3$% will be greater than two standard deviations. $2.3$% of $910$ equals $20.93$.

Possible multiple choice answers are $21$ or $23$. I picked $21$. The test guide says $23$. I assume this is a typo. Anyone think I went awry?

Answer (score 11):

The answer key may be using the rougher guide ('empirical rule') that about $95\%$ of the area under a normal curve is within $2$ standard deviations of the mean.  So about $2.5\%$ of the data is more than $2$ standard deviations above the mean. And $2.5\%$ of $910$ is $22.75$, close to their answer of $23$.

However, your answer is more accurate.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks!

Comment: As someone who reads and writes these kind of answer guides on the regular, I can confirm that this is the case. Whoever wrote the answer choice of 21 did not think about the exact value and just relied on the empirical rule.

Answer (score 6):

I think paw88789's answer is closer to the spirit of the question.

Let $W$ be the weight of the deer, then ${W - 86 \over 2.5}$ has distribution ${\cal N}(0,1)$.

You want to compute $p [W > 91]$, since ${91 - 86 \over 2.5} = 2$, we see that
this is $p [W > 91] = 1 - p[W \le 91] = 1 - \Phi(2) \approx 0.02775$.

Hence you would expect to see $910 \,p [W > 91]  \approx 21$ deer over 91 pounds.